# Can a (conservative) four-force be derived from a scalar potential?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, potential-energy

In special relativity, the [four-force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-force) is the derivative of the [four-momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum) with respect to proper time (a Lorentz scalar):

$$f^\mu = \frac{\text{d}P^\mu}{\text{d}\tau} = c \frac{\text{d}P^\mu}{\text{d}s}$$

*Assuming that the force is associated with a static (with respect to a specific frame) force field*, we should be able to find the force as the derivative of a potential (Lorentz scalar):

$$f^\mu = -g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\nu \Phi$$

But, this lead to a very dubious "conservation law" different from energy conservation. To see this, multiply both sides of the equation of motion by $U^\mu$ the [four-velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity):

$$ \frac{\text{d}P^\mu}{\text{d}\tau} U_\mu = -g^{\mu\nu}(\nabla_\nu \Phi)U_\mu$$

then, we arrive at:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\tau}\left( \frac{m}{2}U^\mu U_\mu+ \Phi \right) = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\tau}\left( -\frac{m}{2}c^2+ \Phi \right) =0 $$

But this is nothing like the conservation of energy since the potential only depends on the coordinates. My question is, **does the above mean that it is simply impossible to think that there are conservative forces in relativity that derive from a scalar potential?**

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation is consistent, a bit misleading. You should view it as a constraint on the possibilities of $\Phi$ since the force $f$ must be spacelike. This is the case here since $\Phi$ has only spatial dependence in a certain frame.

Also, for the existence of $\Phi$, you need the additional assumption that $\nabla f$ is symmetric, the 4-vector analogue of having a vanishing curl for 3d vector fields.

There is another setting to define a “force deriving from a field”. More generally, in relativity, the Lagrangian formalism is more appropriate. The closest analogue of your heuristic approach is the following action:
$$
S=\int (-m-\Phi)d\tau
$$
From which the Euler-Lagrange equations give:
$$
\frac{d}{d\tau}((m+\Phi)U)=\nabla \Phi \\
P=(m+\Phi)U\\
f^\mu=\Phi_{,\nu}U^\nu U^\mu-\Phi^{,\mu}
$$
Note the velocity dependence of the force to ensure the automatic orthogonality to $U$. Now if $\Phi$ is invariant under some time-like translation, say along the 4-vector $V$, Noether’s theorem (or simply projecting the above equation with $V$) gives you the conservation law:
$$
E = P^\mu V_\mu
$$
which you can interpret as energy since it is the time component of the momentum 4-vector in a frame moving along $V$.

The trick to make $f$ depend on $U$, loosen the definition of $P$, and appeal to Noether’s theorem for the conservation law isn’t specific to this example and is very general. A more useful example would be electromagnetism, although it is slightly off topic here since the force derives from a 4-vector field $A$ and not a scalar field. In this case, you’ll have:
$$
f^\mu=qF^{\mu\nu}U_\nu
$$
with $F^{\mu\nu}=A^{\nu,\mu}-A^{\mu,\nu}$ the Faraday tensor which also gives a velocity dependent force. The new momentum this time is $P=mU-qA$ and similarly in the case of a time-like translation invariant field, you have the conservation of $P^\mu V_\mu$ which is the relativistic analogue of what you’ve seen in non-relativistic EM.

Hope this helps and tell me if you need more details.