# Charge is relativistic invariant. What does it mean?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, charge, lorentz-symmetry, invariants

Yesterday my teacher stated this statement that charge is relativistic invariant But he didn't explained this statement. So can anyone explain me this statement?

Comment: Possibly that the charge of a particle doesn't depend on how you are moving relative to it. An electron always has a charge of $e$. What does change is charge density. [Relevant Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_invariance)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we prove charge invariance under Lorentz Transformation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/248688/)