# How is invariance of charge compatible with the relativistic explanation of Lorentz force in magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

It is well known from basic lectures that the magnetic force on a moving charge can be explained in a relativistic way to be just a coulomb force from the system at rest of the moving charge. I refer to the standard textbook eplanation:

https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_13.html#Ch13-S6

By re-considering this "derivation", I wonder however about the following:

Shouldn't total charge of an object be Lorentz-invariant?

So if in the system S I have charge density $\rho$, there is charge density $\rho'$ in another system S', which moves with constant velocity with regard to S. Lets assume a one dimensional example with a wire and S' moving parallel along the wire. On the wire there are marks A and B. If I'm interested in the total charge between A and B I have to integrate

$$Q = \int_{x_A}^{x_B} \rho(x) dx$$

Doing the same in S' I have

$$Q' = \int_{x'_A}^{x'_B} \rho'(x) dx'$$

Now, $\rho$ transforms like time, so it dilutes

$$\rho' = \gamma \rho$$

and

$$dx' = \frac{1}{\gamma} dx$$

So

$$\rho' dx' = \rho dx$$

and therefore

$$Q' = Q$$

See also the accepted answer in:
[How can we prove charge invariance under Lorentz Transformation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/248688/how-can-we-prove-charge-invariance-under-lorentz-transformation?rq=1)

This seems to contradict with the explanation above, that the wire appears to be "charged" for a system of reference moving along the wire with the same velocity as the moving charges within the wire (which is the key statement of the whole consideration). How can it be charged, because this would give rise to a total charge over some distance, whereas the total charge is zero in the system of rest of the wire.

Where is my problem?

Comment: I think my problem was, that the full transformation is $\rho ' = \gamma (\rho -v/c^2 \cdot   j)$ and j is not zero in my case ...

Comment: I think your comment is a good observation. You've also got to be careful about infinite wires. The charge is Lorentz invariant if you start with a finite object and integrate over a large enough volume to cover the charges. I also just want to mention that the arguments like Feynman gives shouldn't be taken to mean that a magnetic field is *just* an electric field in a different frame, but that the electric and magnetic fields are two different faces of one underlying thing. E.g., for an electromagnetic plane wave, there's no way to eliminate either the electric or magnetic field completely.