# System with $N$ atoms

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity

Suppose a system (eg: rocket) consists of  $N$ atoms. It starts moving away from the origin of an inertial frame at speed *0.9c*. Will  $N$ changes and if it changes where does this change come (if increases) or goes (if decreases)?

**Update:** Let's suppose there is no fuel in the rocket and it attains this speed through a sequence (can be a large number) of gravitational slingshots, and the mass 0 we are talking about is calculated after receiving the first slingshot

**Follow-up Question:** Since $N$ will not change and Total Mass = Sum(mass of all atoms in the system), and according to the equation

$$m = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$there is △m increase in Total mass. I want to understand how does this △m came into the system, does the particle mass increase or something else

Comment: Possible duplicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rocket uses fuel to move so the fuel particles escape the system; if you roughly know $\Delta m$ and the mass of the fuel particles you can estimate the number of particles that have escaped the rocket. Particle number is Lorentz-invariant so the particles composing the rocket will remain the same in any inertial reference frame.

If the rocket isn't propelled by fuel nor by any $\Delta m$  the number of particles composing the rocket stays the same.

The relativistic mass $m=\gamma m_0$ originating from relativistic speed is not the "real mass" of the system, thus is not associated to particle number. Instead the particle number is associated with the rest mass $m_0$ which is conserved and frame-invariant.

Comment: Let's suppose there is no fuel in the rocket and it attains this speed through a sequence (can be a large number) of gravitational slingshots, and the mass 0 we are talking about is calculated after receiving the first slingshot

Comment: @ancadancad In that case there is no change in $N$.

Comment: I agree with @Steeven, since particle number is invariant

Comment: I totally agree with particle number being invariant, but could you explain the comment of this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/666534/314115

Comment: Particle number is associated to rest mass $m_0$ (or simply mass) which is invariant as well

Comment: @ancadancad The concept of "relativistic mass", while not "wrong" as such, is not considered useful and hasn't been for a long time. See [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133376/why-is-there-a-controversy-on-whether-mass-increases-with-speed) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

No there will not be any change. Particle number is Lorentz invariant i.e. the number of Atoms that make up a particular object is the same no matter from which frame of reference you measure it.

Comment: But a rocket uses fuel to move so the fuel particles escape the system

Comment: @LorenzoB. please check the comment under your answer